# Testing for collinearity and parallelism with the axes

Tags: regression, linear-model

[Cross-posted from math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/143724/least-squares-regression-in-3space); let me know if you need me to wait there for a bit before posting here

I have a set of datapoints in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (integer or real values of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, for, say. 30 points).

I need to do a least squares regression for linearity. If the data set is linear, I need to see if it is close to vertical or horizontal. How could I do this?

Comment: Do you mean your dependent variable is 3-dimensional?

Comment: Crossposting is discouraged - I've flagged your post for migration. It seems to me to be more relevant here than on the math stackexchange.

Comment: @Marco, no, I mean all my datapoints have 3 dimensions (x y z). If I understand you correctly thats not what you meant

Comment: Can you edit your question and write out the model you're trying to fit?

Comment: @Macro, hows that?

Comment: Linear in what way? I don't understand. Can you write out the model formula?

Comment: @Macro, Okay, I must not be using the term linear model correctly. I need to evaluate the set of 3-space datapoints to see if they fall any line whatsoever. In school we were given an equation for linearity factor R, as described here http://stattrek.com/statistics/correlation.aspx. If a correlation exists, I need to find best-fit linear model as shown here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFitting.html. Finally, I need to see  if it is parallel to any of the axes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3398/discussion-between-jamesson-and-macro)

Comment: @jamesson Cross-posting is bad. Please don't do this again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Collinearity

If all the points are collinear, we should be able to explain almost the variance in the sample by one vector. In other words, the leading *principal value* should be significantly greater than the other two (since we are working with a total of three dimensions). How much greater it should be is up to you to decide. I would say well above 95%, say 98% or 99% of the total variance, should be explained by the leading *principal component*.

### Alignment with the axes

Once you have calculated the leading principal component, it is a simple matter of taking its dot product of the unit vectors along all three axes to determine the alignment. The closer the absolute value of the dot product is to unity, the more aligned the principal component is to that axis.

### Mathematica Example

I'm going to generate points that are randomly dispersed around a randomly-generated quadratic curve. The greater the coefficient of the highest-order term, the tighter the curve, and the closer the points are to being collinear.

```
v = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]; v /= Norm[v]; 
u = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]; 
w = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3];
x = Table[RandomVariate[
 NormalDistribution[0, 1], 3] + u + v t + w t^2, {t, -10, 10, 0.1}];
#/Total[#] & @ Eigenvalues@Covariance@x // First
```

This is what it looks like with 95% total variance (cumulative energy) in the leading principal component (vector in red):

[image: Principal component with 95% total variance.]

If we were satisfied with the collinearity, we would proceed with alignment verification:

```
Abs[First@Eigenvectors@Covariance@x.#] & /@ {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0,
0, 1}}
```

The illustrated example returns `{0.329372, 0.805966, 0.491867}`, so we would conclude that the first principal component is **not** well-aligned with any of the axes.

Answer (score 0):

Although the model is not very clear it seems that you are saying that if a linear regression seems to fit then you are asking a question about the slope of the regression line.  If the line id horizontal that would mean the slope is 0.  If it were horizontal the slope is infinite.  So test the null hypothesis than the slope is 0 versus the alternative that it is positive.  If you reject you casn conclude that it is not horizontal.  If you can't reject the data suggests that the slope might be horizontal.  If you want to test that the slope is nearly infinite you could set the null hypothesis that the slope is a large posItIve value B versus a one-sided alternative that it is > than B.

Comment: I had imagined this, but how would I even compute slope in 3space? Moreover wouldn't anything with zero slope fall on the z plane regardless of whether or not they're parallel to the xz axis? 

Re model being unclear, what other info do you need?

More importantly, how do I do the linear regression in the first place?

Comment: Re model being unclear, what other info do you need?

Comment: What is the regression equation? Is it  Y=aX +bZ +c? Or is one of the other variables the dependent variable? Are X, Y, Z each 1 dimensional or 3 dimensional?

Comment: X, Y, and Z are each one domensional. The regression equation is the one you gave.

Comment: In that case a and b are the slopes.  This is ordinary linear regression. Are you trying to show that the slopes a and b are 0 or infinite or does this have to do with the plane determined by X and Y?  If it is a and or b there are standard tests for whether or not these slopes are 0 or a fixed specified value with the corresponding t tests.  You can't test that a slope is infinite but can test that the slope is some large value B versus the one-side alternative that it is larger than B.

Comment: @jamesson - I think your key question here may be "how do I do the linear regression in the first place?" in which case what might otherwise sound like an esoteric topic becomes merely your unique way of asking about a much more familiar one.  But unfortunately regression is not the sort of thing one can teach in this forum.  You've got a lot of reading in front of you, or maybe a couple of good courses.  If you search this site using the 'regression' tag you'll find recommendations for good textbooks and other sources.